# getAlbums-Call not found in Spotify-Artist object

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to generate playlists from an artist object, but the documented method [getAlbums](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/beta/8a6410b5e6.html) is not there.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The getAlbums method was removed. A new implementation is on its way.